# Add one div only once not as many times as "li" is added JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have divs with same classes where i have got textarea value. there are added in 'li' which is added to body. I want that when i click 'li' show this div text, when i click second div show only second div value and once, not twice. can someone help me please?
here is my code  for example:

```js
let value = $('.text').val();
$('.add').text(value);


$('.addNewValue').click(function() {
  $('.newValue').text($('.add').text())
})
```

```html
<textarea class="text" placeholder="value"></textarea>
<ul>
  <li class="newValue"></li>
</ul>
<button class="addNewValue">Add</button>
<div class="add"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the `text` variable? You mean: `$('.add').text(value);` ?

Comment: yes, sorry @ Roko C. Buljan

Comment: I'm not sure how `<div class="add"></div>` is related to your task...

Comment: This doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to populate a List `<ul>` with `<li>` elements having a textarea value - on button click:

```js
// PS: Don't use classes if you don't refer to a reusable parent component
const $text = $("#text");
const $list = $("#list");
const $add = $("#add");

const createLi = () => {
  // Get textarea value (trimmed from whitespaces)
  const text = $text.val().trim(); 
  
  // If there's no text, exit the function here using `return`
  if (!text) return alert("Please, enter a desired text!");
  
  // else...
  $("<li>", {
    text: text,
    appendTo: $list
  });
  
  $text.val(""); // And empty the textarea!
};


$add.on("click", createLi);
```

```html
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Write something…"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="add" type="button">ADD</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```